# Why is the copy constructor not called when the function returns?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```
Line Line::operator =(Line ln) {
        cout << "Assignment operator\n";
        Line temp;
        temp.ptr = new int;
        *temp.ptr = *(ln.ptr);
        return temp;
    }
```

In the above piece of code, the copy constructor is not called when the following statement is executed:

```
return temp;
```

Since the return is by value, why is the copy constructor not called?

Thanks

Comment: Your operator implementation is wrong: `operator=` should return a *reference* to `*this`, not a new object.

Comment: @Konrad: Thanks for pointing this out. So you mean: *this.ptr = *(ln.ptr); and return *this?

Comment: Yes. The whole `temp` object is unnecessary. However, you should also not be using a (raw) pointer here to begin with. C++ provides better mechanisms.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Thanks! I'm just using this code to demonstrate to myself some concepts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the above set-up it is quite likely that the compiler elides the copy constructor and, instead, directly constructs the temporary `temp` in the location where the return value will be expected. Copy elision is explicitly allowed even if the copy constructor has side effects. However, even if the copy is elided, the copy or move constructor still has to be accessible, i.e., the potential of copy elision doesn't relax the rules on the corresponding constructor to be accessible.

If you feel you absolutely want to have a copy constructor called, you can force copy construction, e.g., by passing the result through an identity function:

```
template <typename T>
T const& identity(T const& object) {
    return object;
}
// ...
    return identity(temp);
```

Normally, you'd want the copy constructor to be elided, however.

Comment: How does that function force copying? Won’t it simply be inlined and then the as-if rule takes effect?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: nope. The semantics are different and copy elision is allowed only in very specific cases (see 12.8 [class.copy] paragraph 31 for details): "... in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a
non-volatile automatic object ..."

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Copy elision is an exemption from the "as-if" rule. With the modified code, you're not returning a local variable, and so the exemption is no longer allowed.

Answer (score 6):

This is called *copy elision*: It is permissible to *not* make a copy when returning a local object by value, and instead the local object (your `temp`) is constructed directly in the caller. This is allowed even if the copy constructor has side effects.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to append the previous posts with the remark that even the copy constructor is omitted in building the target object it must still be accessible and defined. If you for example will declrae your copy constructor as private when the compiler shall issue an error (except MS VC++ at least 2010 that has a bug:) )